# mp3 tag looks different in easyTag and Rythmbox

Tags: mp3, tags

I found the mp3 tag fields for the same mp3 file looks different in easyTag and Rythmbox. why? how can I make them consistent?

From the setting options of easyTag, I know it supports both IDv1 and IDv2 tag, and I turned of the IDv1 tag; I do not know which version of tags does Rythmbox supports, but I believe it is the same as Nautilus, because I see the same tag fields in Nautilus file properties.

Another observation, in Apple iTunes the tag fields are same as they are in easyTag.

Comment: Screenshot?
Do they both support the same tag "specs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP3 files come with up to three different [metadata formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#ID3_and_other_tags):

> A "tag" in an audio file is a section of the file that contains metadata such as the title, artist, album, track number or other information about the file's contents. The MP3 standards do not define tag formats for MP3 files, nor is there a standard container format that would support metadata and obviate the need for tags.
>
> However, several de facto standards for tag formats exist. As of 2010, the most widespread are ID3v1 and ID3v2, and the more recently introduced APEv2. These tags are normally embedded at the beginning or end of MP3 files, separate from the actual MP3 frame data. MP3 decoders normally either read info from the tags, or just treat them as ignorable, non-MP3 junk data.

Check your software's documentation on which of these formats they use and support. They probably use different ones.